# How to extract data from json file in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a below json config file in a project.

```
"Jackets": [
    {
        "GreenHSV": [30, 150, 72, 80, 255, 255]

    },
    {
        "OrangeHSV": [0, 150, 72, 25, 255, 255]

    }
]
```

I have to get the each value of `GreenHSV` `(30, 150, 72, 80, 255, 255)` and `OrangeHSV` `0, 150, 72, 25, 255, 255` in python code, keeping in mind that in future another HSV can be added like below

```
{
    "RedHSV": [0, 150, 72, 25, 255, 255]

}
```

so the code should be able to read `RedHSV` values as well without making any changes in the code. In above JSON, `Jackets` is basically a `list` which contains `dict of list` (if I am not wrong). To get each color HSV value, my approach is below:

```
for i in range(len(config["Jackets"])):
    print(config["Jackets"][i])
    hsv_dict = config["Jackets"][i]
    print(hsv_dict.keys())
    name = hsv_dict.keys()
    hsv_color_name = hsv_dict[name]
    print(hsv_color_name[0], hsv_color_name[1], hsv_color_name[2])
    print(hsv_color_name[3], hsv_color_name[4], hsv_color_name[5])
```

My approach is to first put a `for` loop with the `range` of `len` of `Jackets` so that if in future, new color is added, it will loop 3 times.

After that I have extracted the `hsv_dict` which contains this value  `{'GreenHSV': [30, 150, 72, 80, 255, 255]}`. Now at this point I though I should get the key name of the dict as it will be `GreenHSV` or any next color, so that I can extract its value which will be list `([30, 150, 72, 80, 255, 255])` and then I can get the list values easily. But looks like my approach is wrong.

Can anyone please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hsv_dict = config["Jackets"][i]
```

when `i` is 0 will cause `hsv_dict` to contain `{'GreenHSV': [30, 150, 72, 80, 255, 255]}`.

The problem in your code is that after `name = hsv_dict.keys()`, `name` contains a `dict_keys` object that will yield all of the keys.

You need to extract the first key, which requires something like

```
name = list(hsv_dict.keys())[0]
```

I'm not sure why you're using a list of dictionaries that only have one entry each though. I feel like the following would be an easier and more concise layout:

```
"Jackets":  {
    "GreenHSV": [30, 150, 72, 80, 255, 255],
    "OrangeHSV": [0, 150, 72, 25, 255, 255]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hsv_dict.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object, so you should convert it to a list like so:

```
 list(hsv_dict.keys())
```

Since this is a list you can get the 0th argument like this:

```
list(hsv_dict.keys())[0]
```

This contains your key value